# Parsing JSON (sent via POST) from a global object in PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, global-variables

I'm an average PHP programmer and I've recently built an API that accepts incoming JSON (via POST) data.  I'm using this code to parse the incoming JSON into a global object:

```
$GLOBALS[json] = file_get_contents("php://input");
$GLOBALS[json] = json_decode($GLOBALS[json]);
```

That part is working perfectly fine and the value of `$GLOBALS[json]` is (from the system log):

```
{
   "name": "John Doe",
   "state": "DE",
   "zip": "12345"
}
```

This global object is then being used by a function (in an included external PHP file) to read the individual pieces of the array:

```
$name  = $GLOBALS[json]->name;
$state = $GLOBALS[json]->state;
$zip   = $GLOBALS[json]->zip;
```

The problem that I'm having is that none of these variables (listed directly above) have any data.  I've tried every example I can find online with no luck.

FYI - I've also tried using the `true` option on the end of the `json_decode` function and tried reading it as an array (instead of an object), and still no luck.

Is it giving me issues because I'm starting with a global object/array or am I simply trying to recall the key pair/object values incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

First,
Decode you json using `true` so it will give you an array instead of object

```
$GLOBALS['json'] = json_decode($GLOBALS['json'],true);
```

Then you can access your your data like below

```
$name  = $GLOBALS['json']['name'];
$state = $GLOBALS['json']['state'];
$zip   = $GLOBALS['json']['zip'];
```

I have ran above code on my local machine and output was below once you do `print_r`

```
John Doe
DE
12345
```